# How to union many tables with same name but different schema without dynamic sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic, schema, union

**Microsoft SQL Server**

- [dbo].[MyTable]
- [schema1].[MyTable]
- [schema2].[MyTable]
- [schema3].[MyTable]

I want to union them. For example:

```
select * from [*].[MyTable]
```

Can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
select * from [dbo].[MyTable]
UNION
select * from [schema1].[MyTable]
UNION
select * from [schema2].[MyTable]
UNION
select * from [schema3].[MyTable]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot list the names of the tables without using dynamic SQL.